# Badge - data structure / models?

Tags: validation, data-structures, badge

I'm trying to figure out how one would set up a database and/or model in order to handle various badges. Lets take the Stack Overflow [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) as an example. There are different rules for each and some might be just a variable different (like 10 comments vs 100 comments).

My question is how do you set up this type validation/check within an application? Should each badge have its own method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being that SO runs off SQL Server, SQL Server Agent Job to run periodically to tabulate statistics.  The stored procedure(s) in the job would insert into a badges/etc table when criteria is met.

Triggers would be another option, but their execution can't be delayed for the scope of multiple users.

Comment: How would you set up the criteria? Would each badge require a different method?

Comment: @RyanJM: Yes, each badge would have it's own stored procedure.  That way, you can alter one without affecting the others -- the monolithic, uber proc is not a good idea.

Comment: When you say stored procedure, do you mean in the database or in a model? Sorry, I'm trying to make sure I fully understand how to do this.

Comment: @RyanJM: A stored procedure is in the database

Comment: Shows how familiar I am with SQL databases. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine some are calculated realtime, while others are calculated in processes that run intermittently.

For example, for the badge that appears when your answer gets 10 upvotes, that could be calculated realtime with little performance hit.

On the other hand, for the badge that checks if you hit the daily reputation cap x number of times, you would probably want to do that as some sort of batch job, since you only check at the end of each day.

The key concern is to keep things running fast.  Stack overflow gets thousands (maybe tens of thousands) of questions a day, with probably hundreds of thousands of comments.  Anything that is not trivial to calculate should be run in a separate process.  It keeps the core functionality tight, limited, and clean, allowing high performance.  Running complex calculations in processes outside the core posting system allows you to do so without affecting users' ability to use the site.  If a task is sufficiently complex, you can scale horizontally by just running the same process across multiple machines.

Comment: So then each badge needs its own set of methods to run through?

Comment: each badge is probably its own sql query.  Even if you could calculate multiple bades in one go, I don't think its a good idea.  keep each individual calculation separate because its simpler conceptually.  Im sure some of the SO devs will chime in and indicate how they actually do it ;)

Comment: it would be nice of some SO devs chimed in.

Answer (score 1):

That is how I would implement it if I need to:

I'll set up some queue manager (there are a lot of such software) and write a broker, that will process the messages from the queue.

Each time any event occurs, such as: You viewed a topic, you edited your comment, you edited your answer, you edited another person answer, you upvoted, etc etc - you collect one more messages, with event description. Yes, it will be **really** huge amount of messages there.

After you collect that huge amount of messages - you can start a broker that will process messages by schedule or in real time.

With this schema you could extend a broker to as complex badges as you want.